# Anyone know what the image editor used in this demo is?

Tags: javascript

I'm interested in creating a greyscale heightmap editor in angularjs I've seen something I'm interested in here:

http://tutsplus.github.io/flight-arcade-demos/terrain_demo/terrain_demo.html

But the code is minified and I can't make out how that greyscale image editor works.

Comment: you may want to ask the creator?!

Comment: I have asked the creator nothing so far !